# Getting an Ajax error "xxx" is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have looked through the numerous Stackoverflow questions, various tutorials and youtube vids and so far none (that I have found) address this issue for me...

I have a form to load a single file. It submits this fine without ajax.

```
    <form asp-action="FileIndexView"
          asp-controller="SuburbsAndPostcodesAdmin"
          method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Select the Suburbs and Postcodes latest CSV File:</label>
                <input type="file"
                       name="CSVFile"
                       id="txtFileUpload"
                       class="col-md-8 control-label" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit"
                       name="Submit"
                       value="Submit"
                       class="col-md-1 btn btn-primary"
                       disabled="disabled"
                       id="SubmitFile" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have an Ajax POST method. its called when you click the submit button. All good.

Here is the code.

```
        $('#SubmitFile').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // <------------------ stop default behaviour of button

        //var fileUpload = input.files[0];
        var url = "/SuburbsAndPostcodesAdmin/test";
        var connId = $.connection.hub.id;
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('File', input.files[0]);
        fd.append('connId', connId);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,

        });
```

When I step through this it errors on the:

"fd.append('File', input.files[0]);"

line with the following error in the console.

```
  ReferenceError: input is not defined
  <anonymous>
   FileIndexView:127
  n.event.dispatch()
   jquery.min.js:3
  n.event.add/r.handle()
   jquery.min.js:3
  EventLoop.prototype.enter()
   ...
```

Why is this erroring on this line?

How should it read so it is defined?

What should the file name be  and why?   (does this need to address back to the form)

Comment: *"Why is this erroring on this line?"* Because...`input` is undefined. You haven't defined it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `input.files[0]` because here `input` is *undefined*.

Instead of

```
fd.append('File', input.files[0]); //here input is not defined
```

Try

```
fd.append('File', $("#txtFileUpload")[0].files[0]);
```

Comment: This worked. Just to confirm, the name is arbitary.. the reference to the file has to be a reference to the actual ID where the file is being selected. Thanks to all who took the time to look and answer.

Answer (score -1):

This "Formdata" object seems suspect.  jQuery likes simple objects, i.e.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {input: "A", somethingelse: 2, somethingmore: true},
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

   });
```

In your browser, use the developer options and go to the Network tab to see exactly what's being pushed to the server in the POST operation.  I'll bet it doesn't fit what your server method is expecting, hence the exception.

***EDIT***

Didn't notice until now that you're trying to do file upload.  It is well-documented as a pain-in-the-butt via AJAX.  I've had success with a plug-in called DropZone.  http://www.dropzonejs.com/